# Installing Valgrind on OS X

Tags: macos, valgrind

I'm trying to install valgrind on os x (snow leopard/10.6.3).  When I run the provided ./configure script I get an error saying:

```
checking for the kernel version... unsupported (10.3.0)
configure: error: Valgrind works on Darwin 9.x (Mac OS X 10.5)
```

Has anyone else had experience with this?  Can I just delete that line in the configure file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the release notes for Valgrind 3.5 (latest release as of this writing). It specifically states that Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6) is *not supported*.

Answer (score 2):

The in-development version is easy to install on Snow Leopard using MacPorts. Install the package "valgrind-devel".